# Nested Angular Reactive Forms and Component Reuse

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular4-forms

**TL;DR**: Combining nested components with nested [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms), appears to be problematic. Each nested component must build the entire form hierarchy from a combination of [[formGroupName]](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroupName), [[formArrayName]](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArrayName) and [[formControlName]](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName) directives.

**Detail**: Given a key-value pair is modeled as:

```
{
    "key": string,
    "value": string
}
```

A **single** key-value pair and a **list** of key-value pairs could be modeled as:

```
{
  "one": {
    "key": "Key A",
    "value": "Value A"
  },
  "many": [
    {
      "key": "Key A",
      "value": "Value A"
    },
    {
      "key": "Key B",
      "value": "Value B"
    },
    {
      "key": "Key C",
      "value": "Value C"
    }
  ]
}
```

It looks like a combination of [Angular Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) and nested `@Component` should make this trivial.

I created the following component hierarchy and project structure:

```
│   app.component.html
│   app.component.ts
│   app.module.ts
│
├───key-value
│       key-value.component.html
│       key-value.component.ts
│
└───key-value-list
        key-value-list.component.html
        key-value-list.component.ts
```

The application component, `app.component.ts`,  defines a model and a corresponding [FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) built using [FormBuilder](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  public form: FormGroup;
  public model = {
    one: {
      key: 'Key A',
      value: 'Value A'
    },
    many: [
      {
        key: 'Key A',
        value: 'Value A'
      },
      {
        key: 'Key B',
        value: 'Value B'
      },
      {
        key: 'Key C',
        value: 'Value C'
      }
    ]
  };

  constructor(private readonly fb: FormBuilder) { }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    const items: FormGroup[] = this.model.many.map(pair => {
      return this.fb.group(pair);
    });

    this.form = this.fb.group({
      one: this.fb.group(this.model.one),
      many: this.fb.array(items)
    });
  }
}
```

The model introduced at the beginning should be easily identifiable. `form` contains two controls, [FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) and [FormArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray) for `key-value` and `key-value-list` respectively. [FormArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray) is a list of [FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup)s.

`app.component.html` provides the top-level `form` and the **name** of the control group the `key-value` pair should belong to:

```
<key-value [parentForm]="form" name="one"></key-value>
<pre>{{ form.value | json }}</pre>
```

Form values are piped out for debugging and formatted (`<pre>`). The `key-value.component.ts` accepts two `Input()` values and does very, very little (all the work is done in the view):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'key-value',
  templateUrl: './key-value.component.html'
})
export class KeyValueComponent {
  @Input() public parentForm: FormGroup;
  @Input() public name: string;
}
```

The work is done in `key-value.component.html` using the two `Input()` values to construct a hierarchy of controls:

```
<div [formGroup]="parentForm">
    <div [formGroupName]="name">
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput formControlName="key" placeholder="Key">
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput formControlName="value" placeholder="Value">
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</div>
```

The list view is similar:

```
<div [formGroup]="parentForm">
    <div [formArrayName]="name">
        <div *ngFor="let c of parentForm.get(name).controls; let i=index;" [formGroupName]="i">
            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput formControlName="key" placeholder="Key">
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput formControlName="value" placeholder="Value">
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This works.  But I'd like to re-use `key-value` component in the `key-value-list` component, but I'm hitting a wall. Assuming my application view becomes:

```
<div [formGroup]="parentForm">
    <div [formArrayName]="name">
        <div *ngFor="let c of parentForm.get(name).controls; let i=index;" [formGroupName]="i">
            <key-value [parentForm]="??????" name="??????"></key-value>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This seems a reasonable start, but I don't know what the inside of the loop should be.

Comment: Why don't you make the sub-component a control value accessor? https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor

Comment: On `key-value`? And. Should that be _necessary_? It may be _possible_, but it feels a little involved for merely rendering a list of editable components?

Comment: Why `any`? Isn't each one representing a single key-value? Perhaps you could [edit] to clarify, there's a lot going on in your question.

Comment: Sorry, I made a bad typo. `any-value` should have been `key-value` (fixed previous comment too).

Comment: I don't have a solution for you but I do want to raise couple of questions:
1. The way you construct your `one` is to make it as a `FormGroup` and `hello-component` is used to render a `FormGroup` with 2 controls: `key` and `value'. However, your `many` is a `FormArray` of `FormControls`, not `FormArray` of `FormGroups`. Hence, I do not think it is possible to "re-use" `hello-component` in `hello-list`
2. As you "re-use" `hello`, you also "re-render" the `parentForm` in your `hello` template.

Comment: It's a `FormArray` of `FormGroups` (I just didn't declare the type explicitly). I've updated the question from `any[]` to `FormGroup[]` to make this clearer.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you don't need to pass both, FormGroup instance and FormGroupName to the child component, either one will do. Arrays are a bit trickier than  single control but something like this should work:

```
<div [formGroup]="parentForm">
    <div [formArrayName]="name">
        <div *ngFor="let c of parentForm.get(name).controls; let i=index;">
            <key-value [parentForm]="c"></key-value>
            <!--<key-value [name]="i"></key-value> this should also work-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```